# Haskell - insert an element into nth position in an 2D array

Tags: haskell

How do I insert an element into a 2D array?
Here is an example:

```
insert2D 732 2 1 [[1..3],[4..6],[7..9]] = [[1, 2, 3], 
                [4, 5, 732],[7, 8, 9]]
```

I managed to do it with list:

```
insert :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
insert x n xs = take n xs ++ [x] ++ drop (n + 1) xs
```

Comment: Well it is quite similar, except that you first consider the "row index", and do more or less the same, except that the `[x]` part should be changed with an `insert` like the one you did here.

Comment: insert x n xs = take n xs ++ [x] ++ drop (n + 1) xs                                                                 
    insert2D x n xs xss =take  xss ++ insert x n xs ++ drop (xs + 1) xss                        I tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: No... You need to obtain the row at the given row index, furthermore `take` is missing an argument.

Comment: That is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write the recursion explicitly, rather than using `take` and `drop`, the pattern is easier to see.

```
-- Either replace the old first element with the new first element,
-- or insert the new element into the tail of the list and prepend
-- the old first element.
insert1D :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
insert1D x' 0 (_:xs) = x':xs
insert1D x' p (x:xs) = x : insert1D x' (p - 1) xs

-- Likewise, either replace the old first row with a new first row
-- (which you get using insert1D), or insert the new element into
-- the tail of the array and prepend the old first row.
insert2D :: a -> Int -> Int -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
insert2D x'  0 py (r:rs) = insert1D x' py r : rs
insert2D x' px py (r:rs) = r : insert2D x' (px - 1) py rs
```

Comparing base case to base case:

```
insert1D x' 0    (_:xs) = x'               : xs
insert2D x' 0 py (r:rs) = insert1D x' py r : rs
```

and inductive case to inductive case:

```
insert1D x' p     (x:xs) = x : insert1D x' (p - 1)     xs
insert2D x' px py (r:rs) = r : insert2D x' (px - 1) py rs
```

(The two are even more similar if you imagine a function like

```
-- A zero-dimensional array is just a single element. To
-- "insert" a new element, we just ignore the old one and
-- return the new one.
insert0D :: a -> a -> a
insert0D = flip const
```

being used in the definition of `insert1D` instead of using `x'` directly:

```
insert1D x' 0    (_:xs) = insert0D x'    x : xs
insert2D x' 0 py (r:rs) = insert1D x' py r : rs
```

)

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array, and not a list like your question shows, then:

```
writeArray arr (x,y) val
```